# When I try to play an MP3 with Banshee it just shows an X

Tags: linux, mp3, banshee

I have a fresh installation of Banshee on my machine and I'm having a hard time playing MP3's - it just puts an X icon next to the song with no description. It looked under Preferences and didn't find any kind of enable MP3's option.

Is there a specific bitrate or something I need? The MP3 in question came from iTunes.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You need an mp3 decoding library. Some linux distributions do not include mp3 support out of the box due to licensing concerns. Depending on which distro you are using, you'll need to download and install the necessary packages from a 3rd-party source.